# Wer sagt "Mann oh"?

Tags: dialect, regional

Ist der Ausdruck

> Mann oh

einer bestimmten Region bzw. einem bestimmten Dialekt in Deutschland zuzuschreiben? Hier in Bayern höre ich den Ausdruck sehr selten, und wenn dann nicht in Kombination mit Dialekt sondern im Hochdeutschen.

Ergänzung: die Aussprache von "Mann oh" beinhaltet ein langes o. Im Gegensatz dazu hätte ich menno oder manno eher mit kurzem o erwartet.

Comment: "Mann oh" ist mir nicht geläufig. Meinst du vielleicht "Menno" (http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/menno) oder "Mannomann" (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mannomann)?

Comment: @hellcode Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher. Menno kannte ich gar nicht, Mannomann kenne ich aber das klingt doch deutlich anders.

Comment: Ich kenne beides, Manno und Menno. Und ich bin scheinbar nicht alleine: http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/manno-oder-menno

Comment: @knut Vielleicht schreibt also eher "manno". Kommt aber wohl von "Mann oh"?

Comment: "Manno != Oh Mann" Hat nix mit einander zu tun.

Comment: Zur Info: [N-gramm zu Manno, Menno](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Manno%2CMenno%2CMann+oh%2CMann+oh+Mann%2CMannomann&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CManno%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMenno%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMann%20oh%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMann%20oh%20Mann%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMannomann%3B%2Cc0). Menno ist deutlich führend, Mann oh gibt es so gut wie nicht.

Comment: Kommt angeblich aus dem Französische, "mais non" (aber nein). Mangels eigener Verwendung (Österreich) kann ich dazu nicht mehr sagen.

Comment: @knut Es handelt sich hier aber um Begriffe, die eher mündlich als schriftlich verwendet werden. Auch wenn ein Ngram eine Tendenz andeutet, muss diese sich in der Praxis nicht bestätigen.

Comment: Menno ist auch ein Vorname, was das Ngram verfälschen könnte. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menno_Simons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ob "Mann ey!", "Mann oh!", "Manno!", "Mannö!", "Menno!", "Mennö!" - es sind alles nur Interjektionen, für die jeder selber seinen Lieblings-Idiolekt bildet, und teilweise folgt man hier auch sprachlichen Modetrends. Der Phantasie sind bei der Abwandlung oft keine Grenzen gesetzt. Da lassen sich aber keine regionalen Zentren dafür feststellen, kann ich aus Erfahrung sagen.